# How do I set the number of connection clients in the Redis config class in java?

Tags: java, spring, redis

I tried some configurations. Snipped codes is here : I set maxConnection is 0. When I try to post data to Redis it should give an error. But the program continues to successfully run. When I check to redisInsight: how many connection clients are there; It doesn't show as 0. I encounter numbers like 8,9,11...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj6KD.png)

```
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        configuration.setHostName(hostname);
        configuration.setDatabase(database);
        configuration.setPort(port);
        configuration.setPassword(password);
        
        getJedisClientConfiguration();
        JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder();
        jedisClientConfiguration.usePooling();
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration, jedisClientConfiguration.build());

    }

    @Bean 
    public JedisClientConfiguration getJedisClientConfiguration() {
        JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder builder = (JedisClientConfiguration.JedisClientConfigurationBuilder) JedisClientConfiguration .builder();

        GenericObjectPoolConfig genericObjectPoolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
        genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(maxConnection);
        //GenericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(maxConnectionIdle);
        //GenericObjectPoolConfig.setMinIdle(minConnectionIdle); 
        JedisClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = builder.usePooling().poolConfig(genericObjectPoolConfig).build();
        System.out.println(genericObjectPoolConfig.getMaxTotal());
        return clientConfiguration; }
```

How do I get the connection between redis and java?

Problem is solved with this method:  https://github.com/shenlai/sl-boot/blob/c6ff6efbec0ec7c5a85a9a7c13f6eb8d45f54586/sl-boot-starter-redis/src/main/java/com/sl/boot/redis/RedisConnectionConfigBuilder.java

Comment: Please see examples https://github.com/shenlai/sl-boot/blob/c6ff6efbec0ec7c5a85a9a7c13f6eb8d45f54586/sl-boot-starter-redis/src/main/java/com/sl/boot/redis/RedisConnectionConfigBuilder.java

or https://github.com/morylee/mm-verify/blob/d1ca7d66e95d88c907f9d1fed4f1f36a61e5dca4/src/main/java/org/mm/core/config/RedisConfig.java

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem is solved with this method: https://github.com/shenlai/sl-boot/blob/c6ff6efbec0ec7c5a85a9a7c13f6eb8d45f54586/sl-boot-starter-redis/src/main/java/com/sl/boot/redis/RedisConnectionConfigBuilder.java  @JCompetence

Comment: Don't post an answer in the question, post as an answer

Comment: Problem is solved with this method: https://github.com/shenlai/sl-boot/blob/c6ff6efbec0ec7c5a85a9a7c13f6eb8d45f54586/sl-boot-starter-redis/src/main/java/com/sl/boot/redis/RedisConnectionConfigBuilder.java